# Mysql fetch array and sorting

Tags: php

**I have a SQL table and I want a reverse sorting how I can? these codes work well for sorting 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... But I want to last data on top.
... 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 to table all data**

```
    $adsql="SELECT meta_value FROM ue_usermeta where meta_key LIKE 'billing_first_name' and user_id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ue_stm_lms_user_quizzes WHERE status LIKE '%pass%') ";
$sorgulaad=mysqli_query($baglanti,$adsql);

$soyadsql="SELECT meta_value FROM ue_usermeta where meta_key LIKE 'billing_last_name' and user_id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ue_stm_lms_user_quizzes WHERE status LIKE '%pass%') ";
$sorgulasoyad=mysqli_query($baglanti,$soyadsql);

$mailsql="SELECT meta_value FROM ue_usermeta where meta_key LIKE 'billing_email' and user_id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ue_stm_lms_user_quizzes WHERE status LIKE '%pass%') ";
$sorgulamail=mysqli_query($baglanti,$mailsql);


for($i = 1; $sonucad=mysqli_fetch_array($sorgulaad,MYSQLI_ASSOC) AND $sonucsoyad=mysqli_fetch_array($sorgulasoyad,MYSQLI_ASSOC) AND  $sonucmail=mysqli_fetch_array($sorgulamail,MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++){


echo '<tr class="data">';
        echo ' 
        <td class="icerik">
        <span class="icerik">'.$i.'</span></td>

        <td class="icerik">
        <span class="icerik">'.$sonucad['meta_value'].'</span></td>

        <td class="icerik">
        <span class="icerik">'.$sonucsoyad['meta_value'].'</span></td>

        <td class="icerik">
        <span class="icerik">'.$sonucmail['meta_value'].'</span></td>
        </tr>
            ';
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it just adding a `ORDER BY [...]` to your query?

Comment: i dont want sorting A to Z or Z to A . i need adding last data on the top. But at the same time other table's data too

Comment: You don't need to sort them by a name, you can sort the data by any column you want. Simply use `ORDER BY your_column_you_want_to_sort_by`.

Comment: you mean  ODER BY meta_value  ?

Comment: If that is the column you want to sort by, yes.

Comment: ASC and desc don't help me. because there's information in the same line in another query.

Comment: this code ORDER BY columnname sorting A to Z

Comment: see that code ; 
$soyadsql="SELECT meta_value FROM ue_usermeta where meta_key LIKE 'billing_last_name' and user_id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ue_stm_lms_user_quizzes WHERE status LIKE '%pass%') ORDER BY meta_value ";
$sorgulasoyad=mysqli_query($baglanti,$soyadsql);

and all surnames orderin A to Z

Comment: how can I sort out the data in the query from end to head?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to sort data Descending?
an example:

SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerName DESC;

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_desc.asp

Comment: I tried, but I don't want A to Z ot Z to A. a few different tables have different information at the same level. what can I do for all of them ?

Comment: desc and asc wasn't working for me. i want only results orderin end the top. No A to Z or desc asc .